# Getting WebView AbsoluteString In Second View

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, nsuserdefaults, tableview

I'm in need of some detail. I've looked through multiple books/forums, and I've tried as best as I can on my own. However, at this point I'm in need of some outside help with simple directions, if at all possible. I'm trying to make this as easy as possible to get the goal across, and if you need anything, just ask.

So, here is what I'm trying to do:

**What I have:**
I currently have the WebView view, and the bookmarks view with a table in it. I have NSUserDefaults passing the current URL to the bookmarks view and displaying it (but not saving it)

**What the goal is:**
I need to add an "Add Bookmarks" button underneath the rest of the table that gets the current string of the WebView in the other view and saves it as an entry to the table.

**What I need:**
So, at this point (as a start) I need a method of getting the URL of the WebView from the other view and transferring it to the bookmarks view to be saved as a row to the table.

I was thinking of doing this by calling absoluteString and saving to user defaults, but I need assistance for the code portion. I don't know the full usage of NSUserDefaults yet, but I do have some experience with it.

Thanks for the help! It's greatly appreciated!

- Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the current URL and Title to the Bookmarks view before you open it:

```
[bookmarks setUrl:webView.request.URL.absoluteString];
[bookmarks setTitle:[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"]];
... open bookmark view now ...
```

A full example would be:

```
- (IBAction)bookmarksPressed:(id)sender {

    // Open the book marks controller passing it the current URL and Title
    BookmarksViewController * bookmarksViewController = [[[BookmarksViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookmarksViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [bookmarksViewController setUrl:webView.request.URL.absoluteString];
    [bookmarksViewController setTitle:[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"]];
    [self presentModalViewController: bookmarksViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: That did answer one question I was saving for later; how to get the title!

So, what you're saying is, when you press the button to switch views it passes that to the bookmarks view where it will be ready to save?

Comment: I've gotten a certain distance: I have the defaults passing the URL to the bookmarks view where I am able to display it. However, in your code you provided, where do I put that? I don't understand what "bookmarks" is declared as in your example.

Comment: Bookmarks was the view controller. I renamed it to BookmarksViewController and I put in some sample code for how I would use it.